# WordPress - unable to upload images

Tags: php, wordpress, ftp, permissions

I have a WordPress site on my webserver and have recently copied it to my localhost testing environment using XAMPP (bitnami) to work on it, and proceeded to re-upload the site back to the server without issue.

Now, everything is functioning fine except for uploading images. Whenever I attempt to upload them, it says it cannot write to the directory.

I have tried turning off date/time arrangement of images, I've tried manually creating the folder its trying to use and temporarily setting the permissions of it to 777 and it works. However, when I change them back to 755 it stops allowing uploads again.

Like I said this has only happened since copying my localhost wordpress back. I've read it may be due to the account WordPress is using to create/write files. Is there any way to find out what this account is? And how would I ensure it has the correct permissions? Could it somehow have inherited the Bitnami XAMPP WordPress account since I copied the files/DB over?

I have access to my sites cPanel if that helps.

Comment: ls -al should give you the list of files along with username/group they belong to. And you should be able to change the owner using chown

Comment: This questions does belong on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I felt like it was more of a generic permissions/folder user question so thought I'd try here where the community is fantastic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don't change permissions change owner

> sudo chown www-data:www-data /folderName

Comment: or other owner which runs files

Comment: I guess I'd need to call my web server host to execute these commands for me? I believe I only have access to the cPanel for the site.

Comment: with cPanel you wont do that :/ must be some option in panel to change owner of folder but I do not know cPanel to say where it is :/

Comment: After researching a lot, it seems this is what I have to do to my web server. I'll have to contact my host and see if I get them to do this. Thanks!

Comment: I guess I found how to do it with cPanel , https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/cpanel/file_permissions.htm

Comment: Thanks for that. However the permissions are all set fine (755), the problem is that WordPress itself (and the users in it) is not an owner of the WordPress folders. Meaning that it requires permission 777 to be able to upload anything to the web server. I have no idea why this has suddenly changed either, as it was working before.